# apxs apache module creator compile libraries into shared object linux/unix

Tags: c, linux, apache, module, shared-libraries

I am trying to create a new Apache 2 module, to hold a complex piece of software. The code consists of my own C files, which compile into .o files and are then linked into a .so file. The problem is that my code uses tcl to handle scripting. Up to now, I have compiled the tcl (version 8.4.13 -- yes, it is that old) into a .a archive and linked it to the .o files to create a single .so file, which Apache loads as a module and all works. I found this tricky on the Mac BSD-based system, but was able finally to make it work by:
1. Compiling tcl with  --enable-threads --disable-shared --disable-corefoundation options
2. Link the .o files from my code to the tcl library with this:

> gcc -DSHARED_MODULE -bundle -undefined suppress  -flat_namespace   -o mod_anastasia.so  Release/*.o libtcl8.5.a

This works for BSD/Mac. So now I need to compile this module for a Linux server. Here is the apxs command which should (in theory) work:

> apxs -i -c mod_anastasia.c ana_browsegrove.c libtcl8.4.a

This gives the following warning:

> *** Warning: Linking the shared library mod_anastasia.la against the 
>   static library libtcl8.4.a is not portable!***

And sure enough when I try to load the .so file created into Apache, I get this error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 156 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_anastasia.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_anastasia.so: undefined symbol: acos

So my question... does anyone know the magic formula for compiling a .a file so that Apache can link it to .o files made by apxs?

Answer (score 1):

`acos()` is a function of `libm`. You have to specify, that your shared library also needs to link `libm` to satisfies its requirements.

Try compiling this way:

```
apxs -i -c mod_anastasia.c ana_browsegrove.c libtcl8.4.a -lm
```

This should fix your *undefined symbol* issue.

For the other warning: You could also try to link the shared version of the tcl library instead by replacing `libtcl8.4.a` by `-ltcl8.4` (if the corresponding tcl library is installed correctly in the system). Linking static libraries to a shared library can be problematic and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you! simply adding -lm solved the problem. Superb.